# Dockerhub Registry API URL to access repository

Tags: registry, dockerhub, docker-image

Can someone please help me in accessing the registry API's for dockerhub account. Key points here are:

1. I have dockerhub account and their I have both the private and public repositories.
2. I tried "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/inderpreet20/fedora/tags" and this gives blank string
3. After some research, I tried accessing the images by "https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/inderpreet20/fedora/tags" and this gives error "Required Authorization"
4. Which version of registry API is in use now for dockerhub? I saw the documentation for v2 is also available but with v2 in above URL's i always see the blank page.
5. What will be the actual URL that can be used to access these registry API's.

Here in above points, I have only mentioned about my public repository. My account is also part of one organization where we have the private repository. So do accessing these repositories requires some different approach?

Comment: also tried this URL https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/inderpreet20/fedora/tags but this is also giving me blank json string

Answer (score 6):

`https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/ORGANIZATION/REPOSITORY/tags`

E.g. this will give you all tags from the image `osism/ara-server`.

`https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/osism/ara-server/tags`

For private repositories you have to pass your username and password.